# How to read a file AND make a query at each line?

Tags: awk, cat

I have a file .csv and would like to add information to it. The delimiter is ; .
I had an idea to do so but it didn't really work. It was :

```
    cat file.csv | awk -F ";" '{ print ""$1" "$2" "$3 }' > temp.csv    
    cat temp.csv | while read info1 info2 info3
    do
         read -p 'Give another information :  " INFO
         echo "$info1 ; $info2 ; $info3 ; INFO" >> new_file.csv
    done
```

Everything works except "read -p" within the "while"...
I was wondering if I should try only using an awk command but I actually don't really master this command so....Maybe someone has an idea to help me with that problem.

Comment: you want to read each lines?

Comment: A simple change would be `read -p 'Give another information :  " INFO </dev/tty`.

Comment: At the least, you need `INFO` to be `$INFO` within the `echo` string.

Comment: @ZiyaddinSadigov : yes, in order to add a data to each line (such as a date of birth)

Comment: @Vaughn Cat : I tried but it didn't work. It always says : "-ksh[3]: read: no query process"

Comment: @Kevin : yes sorry it was a mistake when I copied the code, there is a $ in the code

Comment: try it for each line: for i in $(cat text.txt) ; do
     sed ... $i
done

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
{printf "Enter new stuff for line : " $0 "\n"; 
getline newstuff < "-"; 
print $0,newstuff > "newfile" }' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
this;is;my;line;one
this;is;my;line;two
this;is;my;line;three

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{printf "Enter new stuff for line : " $0 "\n"; getline newstuff < "-"; print $0,newstuff > "newfile" }' file
Enter new stuff for line : this;is;my;line;one
hola
Enter new stuff for line : this;is;my;line;two
hello
Enter new stuff for line : this;is;my;line;three
bonjour

$ cat newfile
this;is;my;line;one;hola
this;is;my;line;two;hello
this;is;my;line;three;bonjour
```

Comment: I don't really understand how to put those lines in the code.
I'd like to have the user enter the new information for each line. The result of the code would be a file with the old datas and the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Entirely within awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{printf "prompt? ";getline info <"/dev/tty";print $1,$2,$3,info > "output"}'
```

Comment: It works pretty well, but I'd like to create a new file with those lines. Is it possible to do that in within awk ?
Something that would do sthg like this : print $1,$2,$3,info >> newfile.csv   .

Comment: Oh yes, I had meant to add that. Yes, it's what you typed but just one `>` (it's kept open through the whole file, so it doesn't clobber itself every line). I've edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to do this all in awk, as an solution like that would be error prone and/or unnecessarily complicated.

Try this bash script:

```
> new_file
exec 3<file
while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3 rest
do
        read -p "other info? " info <&1
        echo "$f1;$f2;$f3;$info" >> new_file
done <&3
```

e.g.:

```
$ > new_file
exec 3<file
while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3 rest
do
        read -p "other info? " info <&1
        echo "$f1;$f2;$f3;$info" >> new_file
done <&3
other info? line 1
other info? line 2
other info? line 3

$ cat file
1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8
9;10;11;1

$ cat new_file
1;2;3;line 1
5;6;7;line 2
9;10;11;line 3
```